# Where to learn tkinter for Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to find a good, free, and up to date *online* tutorial/book for the tkinter module that comes with Python so that I can learn it. Does anyone know of any good ones? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always, the best way to choose tutorial about `python` modules is to look at the [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/).

There is a lot of info about `tkinter` there, so check out [the Tkinter page on the wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

Comment: Thanks, I found something there that's perfect and now I know where to find stuff for learning other modules.

Answer (score 2):

I learned it from [a tutorial on pythonware.com](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/). Since Tkinter is a wrapper around tcl/tk, you might want to look at [www.tcl.tk](http://www.tcl.tk) too.